# Django - Best Approach to query latest time series objects?

Tags: django, database, postgresql

Let's say I'm modeling end of day stock prices, and have two Django models for this: Stock, and DailyPriceData (simplified for this question). In reality, Stock has additional metadata, and DailyPriceData has OHLC data, volume, etc.:

```
class Stock(models.Model):
    ticker = models.CharField(max_length=10)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=['ticker']

class DailyPriceData(models.Model):
    stock= models.ForeignKey(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date = models.DateField()
    price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=30, decimal_places=6)

    class Meta:
        unique_together=['stock','date']
        indexes = [
            models.Index(fields=['stock','date']),
        ]
```

Now, let's say there are 50k Stock objects, and each Stock object has ~10 years or more of DailyPriceData objects.

What is the best way of extracting only the latest DailyPriceData objects of each Stock object for display on a frontend?

Using PostgreSQL, I can accomplish the task with the .Distinct method, though this is very slow and not suitable for a frontend.

Should I create another model object, shown below? Is this wasteful? Should I use a signal or management command to keep this updated?:

```
class DailyPriceDataLatest(models.Model):
    stock= models.OneToOneField(Stock, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    daily_price_data = models.OneToOneField(DailyPriceData, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    class Meta:
        unique_together = ['stock']
```

Is there a better way to skin this cat, so that I can query the latest price data by Stock or group of Stock objects quickly?

Comment: Since you have `unique_together=['stock','date']`, why not use `select * from daily_price_data where date = %(chosen_day)s` without `distinct()`?

Comment: Well this a good question - it doesn’t quite work how we want though, when different Stock objects have different latest “date” objects. For example, if a stock is delisted or halted on a given day, it’s most recent DailyPriceData object will be different than other stocks, so we won’t be able to query by specific date, only max

Answer (score 0):

> What is the best way of extracting only the latest DailyPriceData objects of each Stock object for display on a frontend?

I think you can use `stock.dailypricedata_set.latest('date')` to retrieve it for one instance of the `Stock` model.

Or you can use an annotation on the queryset to add a field on each stocks :

```
stocks = Stock.objects.annotate(latest_date=models.Max('dailypricedata__date'))
```

Then you would be able to do this in your html :

```
{% for stock in stocks %}
    {{ stock }} - {{ stock.latest_date %}
{% endfor %}
```